# IsNull is slow, do I have other option?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having the following query:

```
select 
    tA.Name
    ,tA.Prop1
    ,tA.Prop2
    ( select sum(tB.Values)
      from tableB tB
      where tA.Prop1 = tB.Prop1                     
            and tA.Prop2 = tB.Prop2 
    ) as Total
from tableA tA
```

This query is taking me 1 second to run, BUT it will give me wrong SUM when Prop2 is null

I change the query to use IsNULL

```
and ISNULL(tA.Prop2,-1) = ISNULL(tB.Prop2,-1)
```

the data is correct now, but takes almost 7 seconds.....

Is there a fastest way to do this?

**Note**: this is just a partial simplified version of a more complex query.... but the base idea is here.

Comment: Are their any indices on `Prop2` on either table?

Comment: Post some sample data, please

Comment: If your intent is to check both columns for `NULL`, try `tA.Prop2 IS NULL AND tB.Prop2 IS NULL` instead.  That will provide a sargable expression because a function isn't applied to the column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using

```
AND ( 
           (tA.Prop2= tB.Prop2) 
        OR (tA.Prop2 IS NULL AND tB.Prop2 IS NULL )
     )
```

Answer (score 1):

From your description, `=` is using an index, but the `isnull()` blocks the use of an index.  This is a bit hard to get around in SQL server.

One way is to break the logic into two sums:

```
select tA.Name, tA.Prop1, tA.Prop2
       (isnull((select sum(tB.Values)
                from tableB tB
                where tA.Prop1 = tB.Prop1 and tA.Prop2 = tB.Prop2 
               ), 0) +
        isnull((select sum(tB.Values)
                from tableB tB
                where tA.Prop1 = tB.Prop1 and
                      tA.Prop2 is null and tB.Prop2 is null
               ), 0)
       ) as Total
from tableA tA;
```